# Working on a project located in a HomeGroup folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a pc and laptop. When I am in university I work on a project (Or soloution) on my laptop. When I get back home I really want to work on the project using my PC (I got dual screen and ofcourse my PC is thusands time faster!).

The projects are located in `Documents\Visual Studio......` in my laptop and of course this folder is shared on the HomeGroup.

I can open the project in my PC but when I try to build the project I get some errors like this:

```
Error   1   Unexpected error creating debug information file '\\AMIGA\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MiniScope\MiniScope\obj\Debug\MiniScope.PDB' -- '\\AMIGA\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MiniScope\MiniScope\obj\Debug\MiniScope.pdb: Access is denied.
```

'   MiniScope

And a warning like this:

```
Warning 2   Could not read state file "obj\Debug\ResolveAssemblyReference.cache". Access to the path '\\AMIGA\Users\Sean\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MiniScope\MiniScope\obj\Debug\ResolveAssemblyReference.cache' is denied. MiniScope
```

Can someone tell me please how can I grant permission to this projects so they can compile and run?!

Comment: Use a proper source control system for sharing between the two computers. You'll get all kinds of other benefits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a security feature of Visual Studio. Network drives are considered untrusted (as others might change code or inject malicious stuff while you're working on it).

As a solution to this, I'd suggest not using a network share. Instead, use a tool to synchronize folders or a file hosting service such as [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/), [SkyDrive](http://skydrive.live.com/) or [Box.net](http://www.box.net/).

I never used the other two services, but Dropbox allows you to work with your Dropbox folder like any other folder (it's essentially just a standard folder observed by the service). Any modifications inside are mirrored on their server (secured/encrypted) and any PC or Android device you link with it. So you could link your PC and your Laptop, and the tool would do the syncing for you (using the internet or LAN, whichever is available (and faster)).